# Site, Store, View. product visibility

Tags: magento

I have searched and searched and can’t seem to find much on this that helps me out , so I have given up and decided to post. What I am looking for is to have:

4 different web stores all with only one associated view.

The aim is that each of these different stores will be maintained by different people. The products in one store will not be viewable in another store, etc.

To top it all off I would like to have a 5th store that has the ability to show all of the products from all stores and which store they are from. eg if you browse the catalog in this store you will be shown the catalogues from all the 4 other stores combined.

I thought I had it, but I don’t seem to be able to. If someone can point me in the right direction here for how to set this up, I am open to purchasing an extension if it is required…

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

> 4 different web stores all with only one associated view.
>
> The aim is that each of these different stores will be maintained by different people. The products in one store will not be viewable in another store, etc.

You create one website then 4 stores (e.g. English, French, German, Italian) for each store you create only one store view, you define a top category (e.g. Top Category English, top Category French, etc) in each store (not store view).
See in backend System > Manage Stores.
You set your products inside of a subcategory of the top category wished. E.g. you want a product only in the French Store, you set this product in a subcategory of the Top Category French. You can set the category in the Product Edit Page, in the tab "Category" or in the Category Edit Page itself

> To top it all off I would like to have a 5th store that has the ability to show all of the products from all stores and which store they are from. eg if you browse the catalog in this store you will be shown the catalogues from all the 4 other stores combined.

The only way I see now is that you have to create a 5th store with a new top category and you set all of your products into this Top category too. You will have your products for example in the Top Category English + in the Top Category 5th Store. You set the product in this 5th top category in the same way as my previous paragraph.
The drawbacks with this solution, you can only display a product in one language. It will be the default one. The products management will be difficult too if you have a big catalog.
Maybe a module exists for that but I don't think.

You have to know that the search is global and search per Website and not per store.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm trying that out. It's just taking me a little while to get it on properly, I'll be back to reply again soon.